# How to understand reasons for a segfault when linking against a third library?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, linker, segmentation-fault

The program I run crashes with a segfault depending on the libraries I link against and I would like to understand what steps one can typically take in such situations to understand the problem.

The `CMakeLists.txt` file is looking as follows when the program runs well:

```sh
add_exectuable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${PCL_Libraries})
```

Instead, when I link additionally against `Foo` the program crashes with a segfault.  The segfault occurs when the program tries to load a point cloud from the harddisk. The backtrace from gdb is as follows:

```sh
>>> bt
#0  0x00007ffff7ef8198 in std::vector<pcl::PCLPointField, std::allocator<pcl::PCLPointField> >::_M_default_append(unsigned long) () from /usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.so.1.11
#1  0x00007ffff7ef6171 in pcl::PCDReader::readHeader(std::istream&, pcl::PCLPointCloud2&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0>&, int&, int&, unsigned int&) () from /usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.so.1.11
#2  0x00007ffff7ef6aba in pcl::PCDReader::readHeader(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, pcl::PCLPointCloud2&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0>&, int&, int&, unsigned int&, int) () from /usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.so.1.11
#3  0x00007ffff7ef3d04 in pcl::PCDReader::read(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, pcl::PCLPointCloud2&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>&, Eigen::Quaternion<float, 0>&, int&, int) () from /usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.so.1.11
#4  0x0000555555562819 in pcl::PCDReader::read<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (this=0x7fffffffdb20, file_name="/mnt/c/Users/fs/Documents/2017-02-16_KB/2017-02-16_KB_182332_REF_005524.pcd", cloud=..., offset=0) at /usr/local/include/pcl-1.11/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:280
#5  0x0000555555560c94 in pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (file_name="/mnt/c/Users/fs/Documents/2017-02-16_KB/2017-02-16_KB_182332_REF_005524.pcd", cloud=...) at /usr/local/include/pcl-1.11/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:652
#6  0x000055555555c950 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdcb8) at /home/fabian/work/benchmarking/cpp/bin/SerializeTransformations/main.cpp:33
```

At the moment, I am starring at the screen and scratch my head wondering what I can do to analyze the problem. I know the problem is phrased vaguely because of my lack of knowledge of how to dissect such problems. What steps can one typically take in such situation to begin understanding the problem?

Comment: Do you have the source code for the library? Can you build the library from that source code? If the answers to both these questions is yes, then this is just a debugging task like any other.

Comment: Somewhere you have an error that manifests differently once the foo library is linked in. I'd start by gathering information from the likes of valgrind and any other sanitizers you may have in your toolkit.

Comment: Can you also provide a minimal program that you link with the library and which will cause the crash? Start with `/home/fabian/work/benchmarking/cpp/bin/SerializeTransformations/main.cpp` and remove everything not needed to still get the crash.

Comment: Some bugs can take a month to be found.  Compile with all warnings and debug info, so with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/). Use also [the clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) and perhaps the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer)

Comment: The source code for point cloud library is available. [https://pointclouds.org/](https://pointclouds.org/)